# What are the integer solutions to $y^3=2x^3+x+1$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, magma

The question is in the title.

Short motivation. Consider Diophantine equations in $2$ variables. Quadratic ones are easy, and can be solved, for example, here https://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM. Further, Magma has routines for finding integer solutions to some families of equations including (a) Thue equations and (b) equations of the form $y^2=P(x)$, where $P(x)$ is cubic or quartic polynomial with rational coefficients (for the quartic case, the command is IntegralQuarticPoints). Many equations can be easily reduced to these families. For example, any cubic 2-variable equation with no $y^3$ term is quadratic in $y$ with determinant at most quartic in $x$, hence we can use (b) to find all $x$ for which the determinant is a perfect square. The equation $y^3=2x^3+x+1$ is the simplest-looking one for which I do not see any simple way to either solve it or reduce to these families, hence the question.

There is an algorithm for general cubic equations that represent elliptic curves, see:

*Stroeker, Roelof J.; de Weger, Benjamin M. M.*, [**Solving elliptic Diophantine equations: the general cubic case**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/aa-87-4-339-365), Acta Arith. 87, No. 4, 339-365 (1999). [ZBL 0930.11015](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0930.11015).

and also an algorithm for the general equation of the form $ay^n=P(x)$, see

*Bilu, Yuri F.; Hanrot, Guillaume*, [**Solving superelliptic diophantine equations by Baker’s method**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1000305028888), Compos. Math. 112, No. 3, 273-312 (1998). [ZBL0915.11065](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0915.11065).

So the equation can be solved "in principle" by at least two different methods. However, these algorithms (i) are not easy to apply by hand and (ii) have never been implemented in any computer algebra system.

**Update:** This is an update in response to Gerry Myerson comment. I put it here because it is too long for a comment. From the equation, $|(y/x)^3-2|=|(x+1)/x^3|\approx |1/x^2|$ for large $x$. If we could prove that $|(y/x)^3-2|>c/x^2$ for some $c>1$ and large $x$, we could derive the non-existence of large solutions. Now, $|(y/x)^3-2|=|(y/x)-\sqrt[3]{2}||(y/x)^2+(y/x)\sqrt[3]{2}+(\sqrt[3]{2})^2|\approx |(y/x)-\sqrt[3]{2}|3\cdot 2^{2/3}$, so our desired inequality is equivalent to $|(y/x)-\sqrt[3]{2}|>c'/x^2$ for some $c'>(3\cdot 2^{2/3})^{-1}$. However, numbers satisfying this inequality for any $c'>0$ are called badly approximable, have measure $0$, and bounded elements in the continuing fraction expansion. If we denote $f(n)$ the largest element in the first $n$ terms of the continuing fraction expansion of $\sqrt[3]{2}$, then $f(10)=8$, $f(100)=534$, $f(1000)=7451$, $f(10000)=12737$, $f(100000)=148017$, etc. This does not look bounded at all. Hence, it looks like $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is not badly approximable, and hence there seems to be infinitely many pairs $(x,y)$ such that $|y^3-2x^3|$ is smaller than $|x|$ by an arbitrary large ratio. So, an additional idea seems to be required if we try to use this method.

Comment: $(x,y)=(0,1)$ yes, but $2(-4)^3+(-4)+1=-131$ is not a perfect cube. In fact, $(x,y)=(0,1)$ is the only small solution and is likely to be the only integer solution at all.

Comment: This curve is isomorphic over $\mathbf{Q}$ to $y^2 = x^3 - 29$, which is an elliptic curve of rank 1. So there are lots of $\mathbf{Q}$-points; but finding $\mathbf{Z}$-points is more fiddly.

Comment: $y/x$ must be close to $\root3\of2$, and there are bounds on how good a rational approximation of $\root3\of2$ can be. Are these bounds sharp enough to rule out (large) solutions?

Comment: OP, sorry for my error (namely $\ (-4\,\ 5).$ Thank you for pointing out to it.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Thank you for the idea. See my response in the edit to the question (too long for a comment).